# Get all selected items value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get all values from a set of input text in my page and I need to know if someone of these inputs has value *'some value'*

I'm using JQuery so I'm doing something like:

```
$('input.partValue').each(function(){
    int count = 0;
    if($(this).val() == 'some value'){
        count++;
    }
});
if(count > 0){
    // do something
}
```

but could be useful to have something like:

```
if($("input.partValue[value='some value']").length > 0){
    // do something
}
```

There is something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var elems = $("input.partValue").filter(function() {
    return this.value == "some value";
});

if (elems.length > 0) { ... }
```